# Output redirects are not working running Perl program via Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: perl, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, output-redirect

I have Perl script configured to run periodically via Windows Task Scheduler.

```
Action: Start a program
Program: C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe
Add arguments: script.pl config.json > output.txt 2>&1
           or: script.pl config.json 2>&1 > output.txt
Start in: c:\path\to\scriptPL\
```

The program runs, but it gets either `>` or `2>&1` in `$ARGV[1]`, instead of redirecting outputs. When running from the command prompt output redirects work.

What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I know that in your case you specify the "Start in" directory - but the default for it is to be empty - so it's easy to lose it - and hava a case like mine, where the file I was redirecting to actually ended up to be in C:\Windows\System32 - just a note for others who might be searching for similar cases ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output redirection [may or may not work with the Task Scheduler](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/985ce84c-ac55-4fe8-b652-259d5373f747/redirect-script-output-to-file-in-task-scheduler?forum=winserverpowershell). The workaround is to run your desired command (including output redirection) inside a batch file, and to call the batch file from Task Scheduler.

```
script.bat
----------
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe script.pl config.json > output.txt 2>&1
```